# Xamarin forms button with Gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Carousel in my xamarin view.Carousel inside grid view.and also i have a button,But the problem is button is not come to correct place.I want to put register button littlebit upper and full width.

Here is my view
[image]

### My Code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InfutureMob"
         x:Class="InfutureMob.MainPage"
         xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView">

    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Zoos}" x:Name="CarouselImages" >
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
                        <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Margin="20,20,20,0" Grid.Row="2">


        <Button Text="Register" BackgroundColor="#3897f0" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start" />

    </StackLayout>
</Grid></ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things stand out...
First, you define 3 rows for your grid, but the StackLayout that contains the Button is in Grid.Row="2", that should be 1 if it needs to be underneath the Carousel. ( Best for readability put Grid.Row="0" on the Carousel )

Secondly, you don't need to wrap the button with a StackLayout and put the HorizontalOptions to FillAndExpand for the button to fill the whole size of the Grid.